# Is it possible to add type constraints to a Swift protocol conformance extension?

Tags: swift, generics

I would like extend `Array` to add conformance to a new protocol — but only for arrays whose elements themselves conform to a specific protocol.

More generally, I’d like to have types (whether protocols or concrete types) with type parameters implement a protocol only when the type parameters match certain constraints.

As of Swift 2.0, this appears to be impossible. Is there a way I’m missing?

### Example

Suppose we have the `Friendly` protocol:

```
protocol Friendly {
    func sayHi()
}
```

We can extend existing types to implement it:

```
extension String: Friendly {
    func sayHi() {
        print("Greetings from \(self)!")
    }
}

"Sally".sayHi()
```

We can also extend `Array` to implement `sayHi()` when its elements are all `Friendly`:

```
extension Array where Element: Friendly {
    func sayHi() {
        for elem in self {
            elem.sayHi()
        }
    }
}

["Sally", "Fred"].sayHi()
```

At this point, the type `[Friendly]` should itself implement `Friendly`, since it meets the protocol’s requirements. <strike>However, this code doesn’t compile</strike>:

```
extension Array: Friendly where Element: Friendly {
    func sayHi() {
        for elem in self {
            elem.sayHi()
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>The error message is “extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause,” which seems to shut the door definitively on that direct approach.</strike>

<strike>Is there an indirect workaround? Some clever trick I can use? Perhaps there’s a way that involves extending `SequenceType` instead of `Array`?</strike>

A working solution would make this code compile:

```
let friendly: Friendly = ["Foo", "Bar"]
```

---

**Update:** This has landed in Swift 4.1, and it is a thing of beauty!

The `extension Array: Friendly where Element: Friendly` example now compiles as given in the original question.

Comment: This seems to be on the wish list for Swift 3.0, compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/README.md: "... the ability to make a constrained extension conform to a new protocol (i.e., an array of Equatable elements is Equatable) ..."

Answer (score 36, accepted):

EDIT: As noted in the updated question, this is now possible since Swift 4.1

---

This is not currently possible in Swift (as of Xcode 7.1). As the error indicates, you can't restrict protocol conformance ("inheritance clause") to a type-constrained extension. Maybe someday. I don't believe there's any deep reason for this to be impossible, but it's currently not implemented.

The closest you can get is to create a wrapper type such as:

```
struct FriendlyArray<Element: Friendly>: Friendly {
    let array: [Element]
    init(_ array: [Element]) {
        self.array = array
    }
    func sayHi() {
        for elem in array {
            elem.sayHi()
        }
    }
}

let friendly: Friendly = FriendlyArray(["Foo", "Bar"])
```

(You would likely want to extend `FriendlyArray` to be a `CollectionType`.)

For a tale of my own descent into the madness of trying to make this work, and my crawl back from the edge, see [NSData, My Old Friend](http://robnapier.net/nsdata).

Comment: The struct wrapper seems to be the go-to solution for lots of things where Swift generics break down. For example, witness the API methods returning `AnySequence` because they can’t return `SequenceType`….

Comment: maybe in a future swift version: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160229/011666.html

Comment: I believe this is coming. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-

Comment: It didn't make it into Swift 4 but it appears to be under active development. (See link on prev comment)

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that what you are asking for `Conditional Conformance` is coming in Swift 4.1:

https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/