# Teach a (specialized) Swift Array to be Equatable

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, equality, swift-protocols

[ Please vote to close; I agree as OP this should reference [Is it possible to add type constraints to a Swift protocol conformance extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332613/is-it-possible-to-add-type-constraints-to-a-swift-protocol-conformance-extension) ]

I've played with this for a while now and apparently I don't understand generic protocol extensions as much as I thought. I would like to teach an Array: `[NSUUID]` to be `Equatable` so I can hash them *using a wrapper* that relies on `Equatable`.

Here is the failed attempt:

```
extension Array /* I cannot say ': Equatable' here */ where Element: Equatable {
}


public func ==<T: Equatable> (lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool {
    if lhs.count != rhs.count {
        return false
    }
    for (i, v) in lhs.enumerate() {
        if v != rhs[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Am I misled in thinking this is possible? Shall I just bridge to the (unfortunately less type-checked) NSArray?

**CLARIFICATION**

I actually have a generic wrapper around the dictionary in question, so it accepts two type parameters: `<K: Hashable, V: Equatable>` and creates & maintains an internal Dictionary using those. It is the instantiation of this wrapper that fails:

```
class HashWrapper<K, V where K: Hashable, V: Equatable> {
    private var _internalHash: Dictionary<K, V>
    // overload [], do stuff before forwarding it to _internalHash, etc.

    subscript(key: K) -> V? {
        get {
            return _internalHash[key]
        }
        set {
            // *This* is the real reason I wanted Equatable
            if _internalHash[key] == newValue {
                Util.log("Warning: called set with same value as before at key \(key)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is my current "solution" that is typologically awful but functions as long as I dare not compare other kinds of arrays:

```
extension Array: Equatable {} // Yes we'll blatantly lie, cannot have both type constraints and protocol conformance

public func ==<T> (lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool {
    if lhs.count != rhs.count {
        return false
    }
    for (i, v) in lhs.enumerate() {
        if let nslv = v as? NSObject, nsrv = rhs[i] as? NSObject {
            if nslv != nsrv {
                return false
            }
        }
        else {
            return false // Oh *my*. So very wrong.
        } 
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `[NSUUID]` should be Equatable since `NSUUID` inherits from NSObject. And `==` already works on Arrays with Equatable elements.

Comment: But that's not what the compiler says: "/XYZ.swift:16:46: Type 'MediaNodePath' (aka 'Array<NSUUID>') does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'"

Comment: @TroyT: Edited to explain

Comment: Will definitely say that your wrapper is the issue — overloading `==` for an array of Equatable objects is pretty redundant.

Comment: @TroyT: Very true, apparently Dictionary itself places no constraints on <V>. Clarified further in code snippet.

Comment: @BaseZen: At present, this is not possible in Swift, see for example
[Why can't I make Array<T: Equatable> conform to Equatable?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172) for a discussion
in the Apple developer forum.

Comment: @Martin R What's the convention for "you can't do that" questions? Should you post that as the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: This seems to be the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332613/is-it-possible-to-add-type-constraints-to-a-swift-protocol-conformance-extension (with a good answer), so my suggestion would be to close this as duplicate.

Comment: Ah OK thank you. Can I self-close as duplicate somehow or do I need to wait for enough votes? (I have added my vote)

Comment: This seems to be on the wish list for Swift 3.0, compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/README.md: "... the ability to make a constrained extension conform to a new protocol (i.e., an array of Equatable elements is Equatable) ..."