# Swift generic class which could take Array of elements or single element

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I would like to make generic class which will be able to take Parsable type, or Array of Parsable type. Logic for both are almost the same so i don't want to make two different class for this operation. Is it possible to solve it using Swift generics, or protocol associatedtype types?

```
protocol Parsable: class {
    associatedtype Type
    static func objectFromDictionary(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Type?
    func importFromDictionary(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
}

class ParseOperation<T: Parsable>: NSOperation {
    func execute() -> T {

    }
}

class ParseOperation<T where T: SequenceType, T.Generator.Element == Parsable>: NSOperation {
    func execute() -> T {
        // Do parsing
    }
}
```

This i how i would like to work:

```
class ParseOperation<T where T: SequenceType, T.Generator.Element == Parsable OR T: Parsable>: NSOperation {
    func execute() -> T {
        // Do parsing
    }
}
```

In my current implementation i am using enum which looks little bit ugly:

```
class ParseOperation<T where T: NSManagedObject, T:Parsable>: NSOperation {
    var responseToParse: AnyObject?
    var parseType: ParseType

    var parsedObjects: [T]?

    init(parseType: ParseType) {}

    func execute() {
        var objects: [NSManagedObject] = []

        if self.parseType == .Single {
            if let responseToParse = self.responseToParse as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>,
                let parsedObject = T.objectFromDictionary(responseToParse, inContext: localContext) {
                objects.append(parsedObject)
            }
        } else if self.parseType == .Array {
            if let responseToParse = self.responseToParse as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
                for dictionary in responseToParse {
                    if let parsedObject = T.objectFromDictionary(dictionary, inContext: localContext) {
                        objects.append(parsedObject)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.parsedObjects = objects
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show how you accept input (neither case shows it) and what is the output difference (your two cases return a single T and it's not clear to me if this is intended or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified @RonaldMartin 's answer to show how `ParsableArray` might help you. It don't need to take input of `Parsable` elements, just implement `parse` function this way:

```
protocol Parsable {
    associatedtype T

    static func parse(input: AnyObject) -> T?
}

struct ParsableArray<TElement where TElement: Parsable>: Parsable {
    static func parse(input: AnyObject) -> [TElement.T]? {
        guard let arrayInput = input as? [AnyObject] else {
            return nil
        }

        return arrayInput.flatMap(TElement.parse)
    }
}
```

I've renamed `objectFromDictionary` to `parse` because it's need to take `AnyObject` not the `Dictionary` to be able to parse array. You can add `context` or whatever you like to `parse` method, of course.

If `Parsable` done this way then `ParseOperation` becomes very simple:

```
class ParseOperation<T where T: Parsable>: NSOperation {
    let input: AnyObject

    var result: T.T?

    init(input: AnyObject) {
        self.input = input
    }

    override func main() {
        result = T.parse(input)
    }
}
```

Then, you can parse arrays this way (**note**: this is only to demonstrate how to create `ParseOperation`; `S` is just some `Parsable` struct):

```
let op = ParseOperation<ParsableArray<S>>(input: [["1": 5, "2": 6], ["3": 10]])
op.main()

var r: [S]? = op.result
```

I hope, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the type constraint system is not designed to handle *OR* constraints. However, it should still be possible to do what you're asking.

One approach is to represent both singleton `Parsables` and collections of `Parsables` under a single type that you can use to constrain `ParseOperation`. The neatest way to do this would be to extend `Array` (or `SequenceType`, `CollectionType`, etc.) to conform to the `Parsable` type as well, but [this is not yet possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33333257/4499783) as of Xcode 7.3. You can use the same workaround from that linked question and add an intermediate class to represent `Parsable` arrays:

```
class ParsableArray: Parsable {
    let array: [Parsable]

    init(array: [Parsable]) {
        self.array = array
    }

    // Parsable conformance...
}
```

Now, you can just use the original protocol for your type constraint:

```
class ParseOperation<T: Parsable>: NSOperation {
    func execute() -> T {
        // Do parsing
    }
}
```

Comment: This is now how i would expect it to work, ParsableArray take array of Parsable objects, but don't have it parsed yet, just i am pointing to what Parsable class will i be parsing data, so it isn't possible to pass [Parsable] objects here. So probably it cannot be done right now..

Comment: `ParsableArray` should be generic too or you'll lose type safety

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be able to do this:

```
// This DOES NOT compile as of XCode 7.3
extension Array: Parsable where Element: Parsable {
    // Parsable implementation
}
```

However it currently **doesn't work**.

---

Currently you have to rely on a wrapper struct:

```
struct ParsableArray<Element: Parsable>: Parsable {
    let array: [Element]
    init(_ array: [Element]) {
        self.array = array
    }

    // Parsable implementation
}
```

You can also implement a convenience method for `[Parsable]` arrays:

```
extension Array where Element: Parsable {
    func toParsable() -> ParsableArray<Element> {
        return ParsableArray(self)
    }
}
```

So you could execute your method like this:

```
let array = [Parsable]()
parse(array.toParsable()) // Equivalent to: parse(ParsableArray(array))
```