# Swift: equatable dictionary cannot be passed to a generic function

Tags: swift, generics

I really need to pass any equatable structs/types/objects to this `setEquatable` function.
Any idea how can I solve this problem?
[image]

```
public func ==(l: [String: String], r: [String: String]) -> Bool {
    return true // just a stub
}

func setEquatable<T: Equatable>(v: T) {
    //...
}

let isEqual = ["1": "2"] == ["1": "2"]
setEquatable(v: ["1": "2"])
```

**For people who vote for closing the question due to duplication:** I would not close the question as duplication because that way you will not prevent the same question being asked again in future. People who have problems with their code and want to understand the gist will find this question very useful. They most probably would not know anything about conditional conformance, but they have their code that doesn't compile.

Comment: The problem is that `Dictionary` does not conform to `Equatable`, even if both keys and values are equatable. As far as I know, there is no solution for that.

Comment: @MartinR are you considering it as a bug?

Comment: Once Swift supports [conditional conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-), you'd be able to easily get this to work. Until then, the best you're probably going to be able to do is write a separate overload of `setEquatable(_:)` to deal with `[String:String]` inputs (or a generic overload for dictionaries, where the `Value` is `Equatable`)

Comment: It is a "well-known restriction" and the same reason why arrays of equatable elements are not equatable. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332613/is-it-possible-to-add-type-constraints-to-a-swift-protocol-conformance-extension, https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160229/011666.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332613/is-it-possible-to-add-type-constraints-to-a-swift-protocol-conformance-extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of Swift's type system that is well-known and on the roadmap to fix. The specific feature being discussed to fix this is "conditional conformance" to protocols for generic types. In essence, the Dictionary type can't be universally declared Equatable, because you don't know up front how to compare every possible type of value it may hold (some of which might not themselves be Equatable).

Conditional conformance would allow you to create an extension that says that Dictionary *sometimes* conforms to Equatable, specifically under the *condition* when its Value type is Equatable. And in that case, Dictionary equality can be defined as a function that compares the equality of all keys and all values in both Dictionary instances being checked.

Here is a summary of this feature and others under consideration:

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-

Until this type system upgrade is implemented though, there is unfortunately no way to treat any Dictionary as Equatable directly. You can however create Equatable-conforming wrapper types around Dictionaries, or overload your `setEquatable` function to also accept Dictionaries with Equatable values and handle accordingly.