# Workaround for conditional conformance in Swift (was: Adding protocol to a constrained generic types)

Tags: swift

The code snippet below demonstrates the problem I am trying to solve.

```
import Foundation

protocol Printable {
    func className() -> String
}

class SomeType: Printable {
    func className() -> String {
        return "SomeType"
    }
}

class List<T> {
}

extension List where T: SomeType {
    func className() -> String {
        return "List<SomeType>"
    }
}

func test(type: Any, message: String) {
    guard type is Printable else {
        print("\(message): ERROR")
        return
    }
    print("\(message): SUCCESS")
}

let s: Any = SomeType()
test(type: s, message: "#1")

let slist1: Any = List<Any>()
test(type: slist1, message: "#2")

let slist2: Any = List<SomeType>()
test(type: slist2, message: "#3")
```

How can I get this:

```
> #1: SUCCESS  <--- as expected
> #2: ERROR    <--- it's okay
> #3: SUCCESS  <--- I am getting ERROR instead
```

It seems that adding a protocol to this line would do the trick:

```
extension List: Printable where T: SomeType { // COMPILE ERROR
```

But unfortunately, this is not allowed.

Another way to do it could be to use:

```
extension List where T: Printable { // COMPILES OK in Swift 2.3 but doesn't work. COMPILE ERROR in Swift 3.0
```

But again, no luck passing the test.

What else can I do to add a protocol to a constrained generic type?

Comment: There is no [conditional conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-) in Swift (yet) – you can usually workaround this by overloading functions that, for example expect a `Printable` input with a function that also expects a `List<T>` input, where `T` can be constrained to some protocol. Or you can create a wrapper type in order to represent a `List<T>` instance where `T` conforms to some protocol – you can then conform that wrapper to `Printable`.

Comment: If you could write an answer with some examples of your suggestions, this would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: My apologies for not getting back to you sooner. Looking again at your code, as your `test` function has an `Any` input, and you're looking to deal with types at runtime – overloading won't be much use to you (if you are able to preserve static types, then it would). As far as creating a wrapper type goes, [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332613/is-it-possible-to-add-type-constraints-to-a-swift-protocol-conformance-extension) covers it pretty well (mark as dupe?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An updated answer now that we have Swift 4.2, conditional conformance is now added as a feature.

From their [spec on Github](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md), this sort of code is now valid

```
   extension List : Printable where T: SomeType {
       func className() -> String {
           return "List<SomeType>"
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so in your guard you're asking "if this is Printable then print success else print Error" and with your first example you have s which is SomeType which is printable. That's fine.

After that you have slist1 which is type `List<Any>` which is definitely not of type printable and you get "Error". That's fine

Next you have `List<SomeType>`. Now you have a class extension that defines T to be SomeType, correct? But you're only defining T to be SomeType and not the actual **List** so when you pass the entire List into the test function you're not going to get your test to pass because `List<AnyTypeHere>` is not Printable because the list itself doesn't implement Printable.

Now the question is, do you want the entire list to be printable? If so, then just make it conform to the SomeType or Printable protocol. That's the only way you'll get that to pass other than you passing individual `List<SomeType>` elements into the function. Your function logic is correct but it's just a misuse of the concept.

So if you want the `List<SomeType>` to make that pass then you could do something like

```
class List<T> : Printable where T:SomeType {
  //Add code here that conforms to protocol
}
```

Doing that will make your second test fail because Any doesn't inherit from SomeType but it'll make your third test pass because now `List<T>` is Printable and T is also of type SomeType. I mean, that's just a real quick way to get what it looked like you wanted to begin with. You're not going to have the second and third tests pass at the same time unless you add something extra because the second test is List being of type Any while the third is List being of type Printable. So either one of them will throw an error (because List isn't of type Printable) or all tests show success (because List is of type Printable)

Comment: That's fine. I want #2 to fail and #3 to pass. So adding <T> according to your answer seems to work. Why did the compiler let me compile without "<T>"?

Comment: My guess would be because you can only extend types and List<T> is not a type. List is a type. List is essentially the class name and the generic T is just there to set up for the unknown type you plan on dealing with. But the overall type is still just List.

Edit: That's why when you passed List the 3rd time it would fail. You were saying that the T will be SomeType but the overall type List doesn't conform to Printable so you'd get the error

Comment: I just tried and your answer doesn't work. "extension List<T> : Printable where T:SomeType" returns "use of undeclared type T". I need both class and extension to have Any and SomeType types work. If I remove the <T> with latest Swift 3, I am getting "Extension of type 'List' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause." So it looks like Apple fixed the loophole that allow the code above to compile.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can add my playground but I think you added it in wrong. It's hard to fully capture it in a few lines. With your extension you don't use "extension List<T>" because List<T> isn't a type. The compiler has no idea what that is. List is the type, not List<T>. And you also can't have where T:SomeType in the extension for reasons I just said. If you want to extend the class List<T> then you just need to extend its type List. My answer was redefining the class, not the extension

Comment: Redefining the class would work if I just need to specialize List for one type. I still need List<Any> and List<SomeType> in one Swift source file tough. Therefore, I was using an extension. Which doesn't seem to be implemented just yet based on @Hamish's link above.

Comment: Well if you want List to be able to contain Any and SomeType then it's right to have just the List<T>. You're never going to be able to add SomeType to List and make the entire list SomeType. You'll have the type for SomeType then the type for List. Those are separate unless List conforms to Printable or inherits from SomeType. Your code logic is fine. I think you need to change your test. Don't test the type List. Test the type List contains so make the function generic