# How to declare Dictionary<String, Decimal> complies to protocol

Tags: swift, dictionary, protocols

I've defined a protocol:

```
public protocol VariableTable {
    subscript(key:String) -> Decimal? { get set }
}
```

which merely indicates that a `VariableTable` has to provide a subscript operator for String->Decimal.

Obviously, `Dictionary<String, Decimal>` meets that requirement.  How do I let the compiler know that?

```
extension Dictionary<String, Decimal> : VariableTable {}
```

yields:

```
Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Dictionary' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause
```

where as:

```
extension Dictionary : VariableTable where Key == String, Value == Decimal {}
```

or:

```
 extension Dictionary : VariableTable where Element == (String, Decimal) {}
```

result in an error:

```
Extension of type 'Dictionary' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, that is not possible in Swift 3, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332613/is-it-possible-to-add-type-constraints-to-a-swift-protocol-conformance-extension for a similar question (duplicate?). It is planned for Swift 4: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-

Comment: *mumble* of course all of this is an attempt to work around the fact that you can't subclass Dictionary...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Swift 3.0.

But if all you care about is having this `VariableTable` subscript you can wrap the dictionary in another type conforming to the the protocol like:

```
public protocol VariableTableProtocol {
    subscript(key:String) -> Decimal? { get set }
}

final class VariableTable: VariableTableProtocol {
    fileprivate var dictionary: [String: Decimal] = [:]

    subscript(key: String) -> Decimal? {
       get {
           return dictionary[key]
       }
       set {
          dictionary[key] = newValue
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is really more of a how can I work around not being able to subclass Dictionary question.  Very related to the question of how can I implemented LinkedHashMap for Swift and still pass it around as a Dictionary.

Comment: You should then check the collection/sequence protocol. Most of the standard library methods depend on that protocols rather than concrete instances like dictionaries. If you intend to implement your own data structure you may start with checking those