# Swift extensions: adding where AND protocol adherence

Tags: swift

I can do this:

```
extension Dictionary : MyProtocol {}
```

and I can do this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: String, Value: Int {}
```

but I can't do this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: String, Value: Int : MyProtocol {}
```

or this:

```
extension Dictionary : MyProtocol where Key: String, Value: Int {}
```

What's the correct way to format that to allow me to specify types and also specify adherence to a protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: [How to declare Dictionary<String, Decimal> complies to protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665217/how-to-declare-dictionarystring-decimal-complies-to-protocol)

TLDR: this is not possible.

It is planned for a future version of Swift:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-

much more detail on how it will be implemented: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm an idiot. Just realised the last example gives this error:

```
Extension of type 'Dictionary' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause
```

So presumably it simply isn't possible yet.