# Dictionary of Optional Keys

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

Is there any workaround to create a dictionary with `Optional` keys? I know a proper solution for this would require Conditional Conformances to be implemented, but do I have any options before then?

```
let dict: [Int?: Int] = [nil: 1]
// ERROR: type 'Int?' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
```

Comment: Are you sure you want this? By definition a `nil` key indicates *no value* and the type cannot be bridged to `NSDictionary` because the Foundation type supports only non-optional types as key **and** value.

Comment: @vadian Yeah, I don't require birding to `NSDictionary`. Here's my use-case: I'm building a class hierarchy of the classes in the objective C runtime. This dict will map classes to an array of their subclasses. Root classes have a "nil" superclass, as given from `class_getSuperclass`.

Comment: @vadian It could be bridged to `NSDictionary`, as `nil` gets bridged to `NSNull`.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to add type constraints to a Swift protocol conformance extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33332613/2976878)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update: Swift 4.2

[Conditional conformances have been implemented in Swift 4.2](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md), woohoo!

This allowed for `Optional` to be made conditionally `Hashable`, when the wrapped element is `Hashable`. So you can use any `Optional<T: Hashable>` as a dictionary key, directly!

```
let d: [Int?: String] = [
    nil: "nil",
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    3: "c",
]

for (key, value) in d {
    let stringKey = key.map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
    print("\(stringKey): \(value)")
}
```

## Before Swift 4.2

Here's one workaround I found: Create a new `HashableOptional` `enum`:

```
enum HashableOptional<Wrapped: Hashable> {
    case none
    case some(Wrapped)

    public init(_ some: Wrapped) {
        self = .some(some)
    }

    public init(_ optional: Wrapped?) {
        self = optional.map{ .some($0) } ?? .none
    }

    public var value: Wrapped? {
        switch self {
            case .none: return nil
            case .some(let wrapped): return wrapped
        }
    }
}

extension HashableOptional: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: HashableOptional, rhs: HashableOptional) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
            case (.none, .none): return true
            case (.some(let a), .some(let b)): return a == b
            default: return false
        }
    }   
}

extension HashableOptional: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        switch self {
            case .none: return 0
            case .some(let wrapped): return wrapped.hashValue
        } 
    }
}

extension HashableOptional: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    public init(nilLiteral: ()) {
        self = .none
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
let dict: [HashableOptional<Int>: Int] = [nil: 1]
```

Comment: Personally, I would just make the wrapper type a `struct` with an exposed `Wrapped?` `base` property, and then just refer to `key.base` when needing to access the optional value. Because `Optional` comes with quite a lot of baked-in language features that cannot be replicated on the wrapper itself (optional chaining, optional binding, implicit promotion, sugar patterns, ...), so IMO making a clear distinction between the wrapper and underlying value gives a more consistent interface.

Comment: @Hamish Good point. As you can see, I skipped out on adding in map and flatmap. I reckon accessing the value would just be easier, and I may as well just store it directly. You know, I kinda liked how you could use conditional binding on any type with none/some cases