# How to write generic constraint for optional type in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

Once I write a generic constraint, it only fit the normal type, but not optional type. It will lead to a compiler error while I call it as optional type: `Type 'SomeType? does not conform to protocol SomeProtocol'`.

Here is the sample code:

```
protocol P {}

class C<T> {}

extension C where T: P {
    static func test() {}
}

extension Int: P {} // OK
C<Int>.test() // OK


extension Int?: P {} // Fail, but I need it
C<Int?>.test() // Fail, but I need it
```

---

Updated:

I find a way to solve it.

Here is the sample code.

```
protocol P {}

class C<T> {}

extension C where T: P {
    static func test() {}
}

extension Int: P {} // OK
C<Int>.test() // OK

protocol OptionalProtocol {
    associatedtype WrappedType
}

extension Optional: OptionalProtocol {
    typealias WrappedType = Wrapped
}

extension C where T: OptionalProtocol, T.WrappedType==Int {
    static func test() {}
}

C<Int?>.test() // OK now
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add type constraints to a Swift protocol conformance extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332613/is-it-possible-to-add-type-constraints-to-a-swift-protocol-conformance-extension)

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to do this.

```
extension Optional: P where Wrapped == Int {}
```

If we try to extend `Optional` where `Wrapped` is constrained to an `Int` the compiler will complain that "extensions with constraints cannot have inheritance clauses".

Note: This is currently being worked on under the [SE-0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) proposal and should arrive in a future version of Swift.